# Migrating a site with Forms Authentication to use OWIN Cookie Authentication Middleware

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, owin, katana

How easy or difficult it is to migrate an existing site which uses FormsAuthentication to use the new OWIN Cookie Authentication Middleware?

Has anyone tried this? Any advice for or against such endeavor?

I could not find much information on how to do this upgrade on the web.

Comment: This should be fairly easy. Authorization should mostly work untouched, what you change is the way the cookie is issued and usually this is a single place in your app.

Comment: Wiktor: Any example of how this migration can be done?

Comment: Hi BuddhiP, Any updates about this question? How did you migrate the existing site to use owin? Please shed some light